# spfx rest api $filter date query

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I added $filter date query to retrieve items "expire_date" greater than today.

```
this.props.httpClient.get(`.../items?&$filter=expire_date ge datetime ` +  Date.now() + `&$top=10`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
```

I tried Date.now().toString() also see same exception in console;

> ../items?&$filter=StartDate%20ge%20datetime%201486023536535&$top=10
>    **400 (Bad Request)**

In ReactJs, i can get current date with Date.now(), but cant figure how to use it correct format in filter query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
this.props.httpClient.get(`.../items?&$filter=expire_date ge datetime ` +  new Date().toISOString() + `&$top=10`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
```

It should be as :

```
"/_api/lists/listname/items?$filter=Created ge datetime'" + new Date().toISOString() + "'"
```